# Really very hard recursive SQL query for one table

Tags: sql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I want to find chains in a table. 
The table X consists of 3 columns

```
column1, column2, column3
wolf,     eat,     cat
cat,      eat,     mouse
```

I do a query to find "chains"

```
SELECT t1.column1, t2.column3
FROM X AS t1
JOIN X AS t2
ON t1.column3 = t2.column1
```

Here I have a chain

```
wolf,     eat,     cat,    cat,      eat,     mouse
```

And then I can show

```
wolf, mouse
```

But what is the query for the next data?

```
column1, column2, column3
human,   eat,    bear
bear,    eat,    wolf
wolf,    eat,    cat
cat,     eat,    mouse
```

I want to start from the arbitrary creature from the column1 and find end of the chain in the column3 to check whether X eats Y.

Tests:

```
Show human->wolf
Show human->mouse
Show bear->mouse
```

I do not know how to find the number of steps here to make the recursive query.

Comment: Tag your Database (like Oracle, MySQL, SqlServer etc whichever you are using). All DB has slight different supported SQL function & Syntax. And do you need all direct/indirect prey of the creature ? So you need human bear, human wolf, human cat, human mouse as the end result ?

Comment: As a result I want to check, for example, whether I have a chain human->wolf or human->cat. The next step will be to print the longest chain from mouse.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please see the [How do I ask questions
here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

The second column isn't really relevant to your question so this boils down to a "standard" recursive common table expression where the "child" references the "parent" row.

The following is standard ANSI SQL, you might need to adjust that to the DBMS you actually use.

```
with recursive food_chain as (
  select col1, col3, col1||' '||col2||' '||col3 as chain
  from x
  where col1 = 'human'
  union all
  select c.col1, c.col3, p.chain||', '||c.col1||' '||c.col2||' '||c.col3
  from x as c
   join food_chain p on c.col1 = p.col3
)
select *
from food_chain;
```

This would result in e.g.:

```
col1  | col3  | chain                                                     
------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------
human | bear  | human eat bear                                            
bear  | wolf  | human eat bear, bear eat wolf                             
wolf  | cat   | human eat bear, bear eat wolf, wolf eat cat               
cat   | mouse | human eat bear, bear eat wolf, wolf eat cat, cat eat mouse
```

As you are interested only in the last (final) food chain, you can do that by adding a counter that identifies the level and select only that:

```
with recursive food_chain as (
  select col1, col3, col1||' '||col2||' '||col3 as chain, 1 as level
  from x
  where col1 = 'human'
  union all
  select c.col1, c.col3, p.chain||', '||c.col1||' '||c.col2||' '||c.col3, p.level + 1
  from x as c
   join food_chain p on c.col1 = p.col3
)
select chain
from food_chain
order by level desc
fetch first 1 rows only
```

Returns:

```
chain                                                     
----------------------------------------------------------
human eat bear, bear eat wolf, wolf eat cat, cat eat mouse
```

The starting point of the chain is defined by the condition in the non-recursive part of the CTE: `where col1 = 'human'`

Online example: http://rextester.com/GKTU52621

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do this in Oracle, it has lot of inbuilt capability to make it simple for you.

NOTE: I ignored the second column `eat` as it's a constant here.

```
With hunt(predator, prey) as(
  select  'human', 'bear' from dual union
  select  'bear', 'wolf' from dual union
  select  'wolf', 'cat' from dual union
  select  'cat', 'mouse' from dual
)

 select distinct * from (
 SELECT connect_by_root predator as predator, prey
 FROM   hunt connect by predator = prior prey)
 order by predator;
```

And your result will look like this:

[image]